# Cannot generate SSPI context error, but not if SPN server Name is specified

Tags: sql-server, kerberos, spn

I'm facing this error when connecting to a remote SQL Server via VPN.

The issue here is that I'm do able to connect only if the SPN Name is specified on the string connection, ie: "Server SPN = MSSQLSvc\MyServer.foo.bar"

- I've reviewed the infamous [KB811889](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/811889/how-to-troubleshoot-the-cannot-generate-sspi-context-error-message)
- I've run the [Kerberos Troubleshooting Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39046)
- I've checked DNS resolution names and reverse resolution
- I've checked SPN server name with setspn -l

What's difference between specify the SPN name or not?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your SQL Server is really listening on the IPs that you have registered with setspn -l? I remember a case some time ago where the registered name was another and the connection was made with a virtual servername.

If you have tried all of that and is still not working maybe you should go with SQL Server authentication (if possible) that should avoid this error.